# How can I split my data in small enough chunks to feed to Seq?

Tags: linux, perl, bioinformatics

I am working on a bioinformatics project where I am looking at very large genomes. Seg only reads 135 lines at a time, so when we feed the genomes in it gets overloaded. I am trying to create a perl command that will split the sections into 135 line sections. The character limit would be 10,800 since there are 80 columns. This is what i have so far

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 
'>AATTCCGG
TTCCGGAA
CCGGTTAA
AAGGTTCC
>AATTCCGG';



substr($str,17) = "";

print "$str";
```

It splits at the 17th character but only prints that section, I want it to continue printing the rest of the data. How do i add a command that allows the rest of the data to be shown. Like it should split at every 17th character continuing. (then of course i can go back in and scale it up to the size i actually need. )

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the "*very large genome*" is stored in a very large file, and that it is fine to collect data by number of lines (and not by number of characters) since this is the first mentioned criterion.

Then you can read the file line by line and assemble lines until there is 135 of them.  Then hand them off to a program or routine that processes that, empty your buffer, and keep going

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift || 'default_filename.txt';
my $num_lines_to_process = 135;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my ($line_counter, @buffer);

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if ($line_counter == $num_lines_to_process) 
    {
        process_data(\@buffer);
        @buffer = ();
        $line_counter = 0;
    }
    push @buffer, $_;
    ++$line_counter;
}

process_data(\@buffer) if @buffer;  # last batch

sub process_data {
    my ($rdata) = @_;
    say for @$rdata; say '---';  # print data for a test
}
```

If your processing application/routine wants a string, you can append to a string every time instead of adding to an array, `$buffer .= $_;` and clear that by `$buffer = '';` as needed.

If you need to pass a string but there is also some use of an array while collecting data (intermediate checks/pruning/processing?), then collect lines into an array and use as needed, and join into a string before handing it off, `my $data = join '', @buffer;`

You can also make use of the [`$.` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$.) and the [modulo operator (`%`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators)

```
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;

    push @buffer, $_;

    if ($. % $num_lines_to_process == 0)  # every $num_lines_to_process
    {
         process_data(\@buffer);
         @buffer = ();
    }
}

process_data(\@buffer) if @buffer;  # last batch
```

In this case we need to first store a line and then check its number, since `$.` (line number read from a filehandle, see docs linked above) starts from 1 (not 0).

Comment: @Tvega  Added a shorter way to do this, edited a bit

Comment: @Tvega I added a line to process the very last batch of data, from after the last time the buffer was emptied until the end of the file. Since the file is likely not exactly a multiple of 135 lines that doesn't get processed in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

[substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) returns the removed part of a string; you can just run it in a loop:

```
while (length $str) {
    my $substr = substr $str, 0, 17, "";
    print $substr, "\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't matter for genomes, but generally speaking `'0'` is a false value, so you probably want `while (length $str)`.